# Oracle, PDO_OCI vs OCI8

Tags: php, oracle, pdo, oracle-call-interface

The company I work for currently uses some basic functions to abstract the OCI libraries as a means for DB connectivity.  We're considering switching to PHP's PDO object, but from some quick searches, it looks like the Oracle driver is a bit less mature than the other PDO drivers.  I would appreciate some pro/cons for PDO/oci8 from anyone who has used it in a production environment.

Thanks!

Comment: You do realize that the Oracle PDO driver is marked as experimental, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to me that Oracle is not interested in developing a driver for PDO it's developing it's own driver to keep you close to oracle database... to oracle driver... etc. :)

As far as I've seen there is no problem if you can cope with max. texts of VARCHAR2 of 4000 CHARS. If you need CLOBs (and/or bigger) don't go with PDO_OCI.

I've created a suite of classes "PDOSurrogate" as a drop in replacement for PDO with Oracle.
When PDO is mature enough I can use Refactor->Rename to change it to PDO.

Answer (score 5):

I don't have personal experience with the PDO driver (being tagged as [experimental](http://php.net/pdo-oci) was enough for not even considering it). But in [The Underground PHP and Oracle Manual](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/php/underground-php-oracle-manual-098250.html) we can read the following, as preface to the *PHP PDO Extension* chapter:

> The PDO extension and PDO_OCI driver are open source and included in
>   PHP 5.1 onwards. **Oracle does not contribute to PDO_OCI.**
>
> The PHP community has let the PDO project languish and Oracle recommends using
>   OCI8 instead whenever possible because of its better feature set,
>   performance, reliability and stability. **Use of PDO_OCI for general
>   purpose applications is not recommended.**

The extension is not finished, it's probably poorly maintained (although some [bug fixes](http://www.php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.4.12) get through now and then) and it's been that way for years. I would not put my eggs in that basket.

Answer (score 0):

May be I'm too late to the party .. just thought to add some value to the discussion. I am experienced in OCI8 and OCI8_11 extension and have done some extensive workload using stored procedures/packages, CLOB/BLOB's and XML I never had to run out of options  ..  further it seems very reliable and can handle extensive loads and I have even used once for an ETL(Extract Transform Load) applications to handle heavy workloads... also believe oci8 is the widely used extension .. than pdo ..

Comment: I think you misread the question. Nobody denies OCI advantages. The question is: is the **PDO** driver reliable?