# ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified using php_oci8

Tags: php, oracle, zend-framework, pdo

I am using Zend Framework 1 and connecting Oracle Database using **Zend_Db_Adapter_Oracle** class (it uses the php_oci8 extension).

While connecting with Oracle Server it throwing below error:

```
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
```

However, When I use **Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Oci** class (It uses pdo_oci driver) all works fine, The only issue with pdo_oci extencion is that I am not able to fetch values of the columns those have define as CLOB data type. Also [found this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563732/oracle-pdo-oci-vs-oci8) saying there is some issue with CLOB datatype if using pdo_coi. That's why I am looking forward for php_oci8 extension.

Any help to fix the issue appreciated.

Thank You.

Comment: Need more information. Please output the connect string

Comment: @Bjarte, Thank for commentating. After you comment i looked for connection string for php_oci8 and change it to pdo_oci formate like below. Ex: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.XX.XXX)(PORT = 1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=XXXX))) and it works. Thank for clue :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the way to make it work.

I change the database parameter to below format and pass it:

```
$database = (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.XX.XXX)(PORT = 1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=XXXX)))
```

It works perfectly, Now able to fetch CLOB data type values.